# capture $finish in uvm_component

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want to capture $finish in uvm_component. I mean my uvm_component needs to execute some custom code when $finish is called.

I had used pre_abort call back in uvm_component. But problem is my testbench has multiple uvm_components and they also register pre_abort callback.

I want to make sure that my custom code should be executed last just before simulation exit.

Comment: there only way to "capture" $finish is to use the `final` block in a module or a program. Those blocks are executed upon normal finish.

Comment: Hi serge, my uvm component is a vip, so i cannot use any verilog/sv related things like final block.

Comment: there is no other way. You can play with uvm phases to create your own exit flow, but **before** $finish.

Answer (score 2):

In verilog the only way to "catch" `$finish` is to use the `final` block. The following example illustrates a possible solution.

```
package TB;
class WorkHorse;
  function void start;
    $display("I am statging");
  endfunction

  task finish;
    $display("finishing");
    $finish;
  endtask

  function void done ;
    $display("I am done");
  endfunction

endclass
endpackage

program tb;
  TB::WorkHorse wh = new;

  initial begin
    #2 wh.start;
    #2 wh.finish;
  end

  final begin
    wh.done;
  end
endprogram
```